# MIT/Scheme as a simple compiler under Windows

Tags: windows, scheme, mit-scheme

Is there a possibility to use mit scheme as a simple compiler (without runing Edwin) in Windows?

I want to edit code in wditor of my choice and compile it, but I haven't found and option to do this.

When I execute...

```
mit-scheme < file.scm
```

...I get a window with:

> "can't find a readable default for option --band.
>    searched for file all.com in these directories:
>    c:\local\mit-scheme"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
mit-scheme --band mit-scheme-install-folder/lib/all.com \
           --library mit-scheme-install-folder/lib --load file.scm
```

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to save some typing every time you want to run mit-scheme.exe, you can add the `mit-scheme-install-folder/lib` path to the environment variable `MITSCHEME_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said MIT-Scheme, but check out [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) (formerly, DrScheme), which runs Scheme code well from the command line.